# Amazon Cloud Search Plural Endings (e.g. matching 'soldier' on 'soldiers' search)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

Does AWS cloud search somehow consider "**soldier**" a match to "**soldier**s"? I run the following search (using structured query):

```
groupdescription:'soldiers'
```

and I get correct matches, with the exception of the fact that `soldier` is also matched in the description. What gives? I can't find anything in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the result of a search technique called *stemming*, which reduces related words to their root. For example, `climbing` and `climbed` would stem to `climb`.

By default, CloudSearch applies full stemming to English, which it says will

> aggressively stem inflections and suffixes

So that's what you're seeing. You can read more about configuring it here: 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/configuring-analysis-schemes.html#word-stemming

Comment: Thanks, I found some PDF on it, but it only mentioned dropping suffix 's' from words.